# QML views not refreshing change in same data model

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am using same model in two DelegateModel in separate components. When I add something in the model the DelegateModel with (0, 0) rootIndex gets refreshed but the DelegateModel where I have specified a rootIndex is not refreshed. When I again open the second view then it shows the delegate items.

```
DelegateModel {
    id: canvasModel
    model: mymodel
    rootIndex: model.index(0, 0)
}
Repeater {
   id: canvasModel
}
```

And in another component

```
DelegateModel {
    id: canvasModel2
    model: mymodel
    rootIndex: model.index(someIndex, 0, parentIndex)
}
Repeater {
   id: canvasModel2
}
```

Now when I add something to the root of the model it shows in the first canvasModel but if I add an item under the root index of the canvasModel2 then those delegates are not refreshed.
I am using the DomModel class of the Qt sample project which encapsulates the QDomDocument
If I load the second component again then the delegates show fine.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Have you checked, whether the methods you use to change the model properly fire the signals to update the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was

I had been using these two DelegateModel components in two windows. One used in ApplicationWindow got the model changed signals and the one that I created as a child of ApplicationWindow did not receive events. So the problem was that the child window was not direct child of the ApplicationWindow but was a child of some unknown delegate that got destroyed maybe. So I made the second window as a direct child of ApplicationWindow and resolved the issue.